# I we let A consist of all sets A in R (real numbers) such that either A or R\A is countable, then is it true that A is then a sigma- algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I we let A consist of all sets A in R (real numbers) such that either A or R\A is countable, then is it true that A is then a sigma- algebra?

Does the above statement make sense, or would it be a false statement?

Comment: Have you tried checking the definitions of a $\sigma$ algebra yourself?

Comment: What I have tried has led me to get that mu is sigma additive, and so therefore A would be a sigma algebra. Not sure if I'm going the right way though.